# Error trying to install the Yoeman SharePoint Generator

Tags: spfx-tooling

I'm trying to install the Yoeman generator for SharePoint Online. I've installed v10.22.0 of Node, 6.14.6 of NPM. I'm trying to use the following command:

```
npm install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint --global
```

I'm getting the error "404 Not Found - GET [https://registry.npmjs.org/@microsoft%2fgenerator-sharepoint"](https://registry.npmjs.org/@microsoft%2fgenerator-sharepoint%22). The log file has the same 404 error.

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does the provided URL work in a browser? (It should.)

Comment: I got an error when trying to browse that URL url, but was able to browse https://registry.npmjs.org/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client

Answer (score 1):

I just re-ran the command and its working now. I'm guessing it was temporarily offline. I was able to browse to https://registry.npmjs.org/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client but when I tried browsing to https://registry.npmjs.org/@microsoft/generator-sharepoint I got a "not found" error. Browsing the URL is also working now.